# swift playground error BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

So I have the following greedy algorithm which gives me the following error:

> Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted,
>   reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). The
>   process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use
>   "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression
>   evaluation.

**Class:**

```
// This class represents an undirected graph using adjacency list
public class Graph{
    var V: Int // number of vertices
    var adj: [[Int]] = [[]] //Adjacency List

    public init(v: Int) {
        V = v
        adj = [[Int]](repeating: [], count: v)
    }

    // Function to add an edge into the graph
    public func addEdge(v: Int, w: Int){
        adj[v].append(w)
        adj[w].append(v) // Graph is undirected
    }

    // Assigns colors (starting from 0) to all vertices and
    // prints the assignment of colors
    public func greedyColoring() {
        var result = [Int]()

        //Assign the first color to first vertex
        result[0] = 0

        //Initialize the remaining V-1 vertices as unassigned
        for i in 0 ..< V{
            //No Color is assigned
            result[i] = -1
        }

        // A temporary array to store the available colors. True
        // value of available[cr] would mean that the color cr is
        // assigned to one of its adjacent vertices
        var available = [Bool]()
        for cr in 0 ..< V{
            available[cr] = false
        }

        // Assign colors to remaining V-1 vertices
        for i in 1 ..< V{
            //Process all adjacent vertices and flag their colors as unavailable
            for un in 0 ..< adj[i].count{
                if result[un] != -1 {
                    available[result[un]] = true
                }
            }

            //find the first available color
            for cr in 0 ..< V{
                if available[cr] == false{
                    result[i] = cr
                    break
                }
            }

            //Reset the values back to false for the next iteraation
            for un in 0 ..< adj[i].count{
                if result[un] != -1 {
                    available[result[un]] = true
                }
            }
        }

        //Print result
        for r in 0 ..< V{
            print("Vertex \(r) --> Color \(result[r])")
        }
    }
}
```

**This how I call it:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

var g1 = Graph(v: 5)
g1.addEdge(v: 0, w: 1)
g1.addEdge(v: 0, w: 2)
g1.addEdge(v: 1, w: 2)
g1.addEdge(v: 1, w: 3)
g1.addEdge(v: 2, w: 3)
g1.addEdge(v: 3, w: 4)
g1.greedyColoring() // Fails HERE
```

So I had this error in some lines earlier and it was related to how I used the arrays. Why doesn't playground give a exact error like `index out of bounds or so?` My Debug Console prints nothing... What is causing the error in my code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code snippet:

```
var result = [Int]()

//Assign the first color to first vertex
result[0] = 0
```

The array `result` is empty so you cannot access the first element by `result[0]`.

**Solution:**

Change from:

```
var result = [Int]()

//Assign the first color to first vertex
result[0] = 0

//Initialize the remaining V-1 vertices as unassigned
for i in 0 ..< V{
    //No Color is assigned
    result[i] = -1
}

// A temporary array to store the available colors. True
// value of available[cr] would mean that the color cr is
// assigned to one of its adjacent vertices
var available = [Bool]()
for cr in 0 ..< V{
    available[cr] = false
}
```

To:

```
var result = [Int]()

//Assign the first color to first vertex
result.append(0)

//Initialize the remaining V-1 vertices as unassigned
for _ in 0 ..< V{
    //No Color is assigned
    result.append(-1)
}

// A temporary array to store the available colors. True
// value of available[cr] would mean that the color cr is
// assigned to one of its adjacent vertices
var available = [Bool]()
for _ in 0 ..< V{
    available.append(false)
}
```

Comment: perfect, is there a way how to debug playgrounds better?

Comment: My log prints out `fatal error: Index out of range`, how about you?

Comment: My xcode shows only the error that I posted and not in the log.

Comment: Did you open the debug console? Try pressing ⇧ + ⌘ + C.

Comment: if I switch my Graph code from the seperate class to the main playground the debug console shows the error (index out of bounds)

Comment: @SaifDeen I tested your code in the main playground as well, maybe it is the reason why you cannot see the error before :)

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
```

It is helped me

Comment: Seems this is the right solution for the error in playground, regardless the code that you have